# Forcing encryption on pendrives, diskettes, etc

Tags: windows, linux, security, encryption

A friend of mine is the IT manager in a finances company back in our country. Since in these days they are programming some layoffs he has become increasingly suspicious about the employees stealing information from the company using usb sticks, pendrives or whatever other means of storage. So, I was wondering if there it is a way to make the Operating System to encrypt automatically all the write operations to drives such that the information is render unusable unless used in certified computers.

Comment: Not too important for your (nice) question, but: what is "programming some layouts"?

Comment: Sorry, as english is not my native language I tend to make a lot of mistakes

Comment: Aha, now I understand. Still, it doesn't matter for the question. (You could leave it out altogether I guess.) So, those people are not computer experts I guess? If they have internet access they could probably just use Gmail to upload the same secrets...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the idea is to encrypt the Windows partition (SafeBoot?) which enforces all copies of data within that to be made only to other locations that are also encrypted.

Comment: It all depends on how "data" is copied. It may protect files copied with CopyFileEx(), but there are so many ways around.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, low tech but will surely work.

Disable all spare USB ports. Use PS2 for Keyboard and mouse. :)

Comment: And, disconnect the Internet uplink.